# Printing pattern with only one inner loop

Tags: c++

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   ** 
    *
```

It is easy to print this using more than one inner loop. I am trying to do it using only one inner loop.

Any suggestions?

Thanks all. What if n is dynamic? If n is 10 or 5 or 100 how do you do?

If n is 3,

```
***
 **
  *
```

If n is 5

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   ** 
    *
```

**Conditions:**
Mandatory: one inner lopp, one outer loop, cout statements only. No built in functions.

If more clarifications requried, please tell me.

**Code:**

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int rows = 10;
    for(int i = rows; i >= 1; --i) {
        for(int k = 1; k <= (rows - i); k++) {
            cout  << "  ";
        }
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            cout << " " << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

How do i have only one inner loop to achieve this?

Comment: Replace all but one loop by `goto`.

Comment: @GopsAB It's totally unclear what you're asking about. Provide a [MCVE] of your code attempt and where you're currently stuck with it please.

Comment: Any suggestions? Yes. Show us your code. Any code is better than no code

Comment: this doesnt print the right pattern, does it? Now you want to know how to change this code to have only a single inner loop?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is it still unclear?

Comment: @user463035818 It prints the expected pattern. I want to know how to change this to have only one inner loop?

Comment: your code [prints spaces between the stars](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oPDjbac01FWtXiXG) thats not the output you posted here... Anyhow, there are already answer using various numbers of loops ;)

Comment: @GopsAB I am not very engaged in reopening already closed questions, as there are most likely more close worthy reasons with their 1st edit. Sorry, try to address other users please.

Comment: @GopsAB Just to notice you fairly: I've voted to delete your question actively now, to speed up the process. I can't see any value for future research here, and Stack Overflow isn't meant as your personal helpdesk.

Comment: I don't see any future value in this post. It's a very unclearly stated *plz give me teh codez* question that shows no effort to solve the problem before posting here, has a very unclear (and somewhat rambling) problem description, and as written will not help any future user of this site solve a problem.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Inner loop ? Why would you need such a thing ? You can do it with a single for loop using `std::string::string`

```
void print_stuff(unsigned width){
  for(auto i = 0u ; i < width ; i+=1){
    auto starAmount = width - i;
    auto spaceAmount = i;
    std::cout << std::string{spaceAmount, ' '} << std::string{starAmount, '*'} << '\n';
  }
}
```

If you really need an inner loop then just replace the use of `std::string`'s constructor with a loop :

```
void print_stuff(unsigned width){
  for(auto i = 0u ; i < width ; i+=1){
    //auto starAmount = width - i;
    auto spaceAmount = i;

    for(auto j = 0u ; j < width ; j+=1)
      std::cout << (j < spaceAmount ? ' ' : '*');
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: Must to use one outer and inner loops

Comment: edited to add a solution using an inner loop

Comment: `i+=1`?  Why not `++i`?

Comment: Old habits die hard, it would achieve the same thing though

Comment: Thanks vivick. I was thinking in a different way.

Comment: *Inner loop? Why would you need such a thing?* Because that's what the homework assignment specifies.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the late input after the OP's and my edits

Comment: The quoted text comes from the current content of your post. That means it's not *late input*. The question is still clearly a homework assignment, which means the comment is still relevant.